# Checking Citizenship Application Progress

Tags: uk-citizenship

Is there any way to track the progress of a citizenship application? I sent my son's in late March, and have heard nothing since his biometrics were entered in mid April. It seems weird to me that there is no way to check on it's status? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that is no longer available as of mid-December 2017. It seems it was more hassle for the UKVI than they judged it was worth to themselves and their paying applicants.